# Creating variables from Python Dictionary

Tags: python, variables, dictionary

I am writing my own small command line interface in Python. One of the commands is 'export', which basically creates a variable. For example:

```
> export NUM=15
```

Now, NUM will equal '15'. And if I use 'NUM' with any other command in my CLI, then it equate it to the number '15', e.g. I have another command 'hex' that converts decimal to hex:

```
> hex NUM
```

The output should be 'F', but the program doesn't recognize NUM=15. I declared my variables dictionary outside the function. I won't post the entire `CLI.py`, but here is the export function. Basically, I need to assign `key=value` in the variables dictionary.

```
def CommandExport(args):
  if (len(args) == 0):
     print(variables)
  else:
     for line in args:
        args = line.split('=')
        ENV = args[0]
        value = args[1]
        if (int(args[1]) == True):
           value = int(value)
        else:
           value = str(value)
        variables[ENV] = (value)
        for ENV, value in variables.items():
           vars()[ENV] = (value)
           return(ENV)
           return(value)
           return(variables)
```

Seems like it should work but it doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: `return(value)` and `return(variables)` will never get executed as the function will return after the first call, `return(ENV)`. Instead, `return ENV, value, variables` there's no need for the parentheses either.

Comment: @DavidG even that's not right, because those return statements are within a for loop so it will return after the first iteration. I don't think OP actually needs to return at all though.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with this code, many of which have to do with a misunderstanding of some of python's principles

- `variables`:
  What is `variables`? Is this some variable in the module namespace
- `args`

  for line in args:
      args = line.split('=')

Always be wary when overwriting variables. Some languages have a scope for each block of code, but in python

- `int`

  ```
  if (int(args[1]) == True):
     value = int(value)
  else:
     value = str(value)
  ```

Here you ask python to convert the second item of the `args` list to an integer, and then compare it to True. This test will only pass when `args[1]` is `integer 1`, `float 1.0`, `boolean True` or `string '1'`, since `True` has integer value 1. Something like this would be more suited

```
try:
    value = int(value)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

This tries to convert it to an int, when it fails, value remainst the string in `args[1]`

All in all I think you need to refresh the python basics. If you want help with this specific issue, I advise you to post the complete `CLI.py`, together with examples of how it should be called and what it should do.

If you want to parse a command and its arguments, I would do something like this

​

```
def convert_int(value):
    try:
        return int(value)
    except ValueError:
        return value

def parse_arguments(arguments):
    for arg in arguments:
        key, value = arg.split('=')
        yield key, convert_int(value)

def parse_command(input_string):
    command, *argument_list = input_string.split(' ')
    arguments =dict(parse_arguments(argument_list))
    return command, arguments
```

> ```
> parse_command('my_command arg0=a0 arg1=val1 arg2=2')
> ```

```
('my_command', {'arg0': 'a0', 'arg1': 'val1', 'arg2': 2})
```

This method can then be used in a `Class` you use to keep your environment and variable